Unable to connect to mongodb replica set running in docker
Here's how I created the replica set
version: "3.0"

volumes:
  ac-mongo-keys1:
  ac-mongo-data-10:
  ac-mongo-data-20:
  ac-mongo-data-30:

networks:
  ac-cluster10:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 172.10.6.0/24

services:

  ac-mongo-keys1:
    image: depop/openssl-bats
    volumes:
      - ac-mongo-keys1:/mongo-conf
    command: 'bash -c "openssl rand -base64 741 > /mongo-conf/mongodb-keyfile; chmod 600 /mongo-conf/mongodb-keyfile; chown 999 /mongo-conf/mongodb-keyfile"'

  # Node1
  ac-mongo-node10:
    container_name: ac-mongo-node10
    image: mongo:latest
    volumes:
      - ac-mongo-keys1:/opt/keyfile
      - ac-mongo-data-10:/data/db
    env_file:
      ./mongod.env
    ports:
      - 30010:27017
    command: 'mongod --auth --keyFile /opt/keyfile/mongodb-keyfile --replSet ac-dev'
    depends_on:
      - ac-mongo-keys1
    networks:
      ac-cluster10:

  # Node2
  ac-mongo-node20:
    container_name: ac-mongo-node20
    image: mongo:latest
    volumes:
      - ac-mongo-keys1:/opt/keyfile
      - ac-mongo-data-20:/data/db
    env_file:
      ./mongod.env
    ports:
      - 30011:27017
    command: 'mongod --auth --keyFile /opt/keyfile/mongodb-keyfile --replSet ac-dev'
    depends_on:
      - ac-mongo-keys1
    networks:
      ac-cluster10:

  # Node3
  ac-mongo-node30:
    container_name: ac-mongo-node30
    image: mongo:latest
    volumes:
      - ac-mongo-keys1:/opt/keyfile
      - ac-mongo-data-30:/data/db
    env_file:
      ./mongod.env
    ports:
      - 30012:27017
    command: 'mongod --auth --keyFile /opt/keyfile/mongodb-keyfile --replSet ac-dev'
    depends_on:
      - ac-mongo-keys1
    networks:
      ac-cluster10:

I initiated with this
rs.initiate({_id: "ac-dev", members: [{_id: 0, host: "ac-mongo-node10:27017"}, {_id: 1, host: "ac-mongo-node20:27017"}, {_id: 2, host: "ac-mongo-node30:27017"}]});

I added ac-mongo-node10, ac-mongo-node20 and ac-mongo-node30 in my hosts file as well.
I tried below to connect to replica but to no avail.
mongo "mongodb://root:root@ac-mongo-node10:30010,ac-mongo-node20:30011,ac-mongo-node30:30012/ac_app?authSource=admin&replicaSet=ac-dev"

This is what I get
2024-07-01T09:35:15.467+0530 I  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Confirmed replica set for ac-dev is ac-dev/ac-mongo-node10:27017,ac-mongo-node20:27017,ac-mongo-node30:27017
2024-07-01T09:35:15.467+0530 I  CONNPOOL [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Connecting to ac-mongo-node10:27017
2024-07-01T09:35:15.467+0530 I  CONNPOOL [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Connecting to ac-mongo-node30:27017
2024-07-01T09:35:15.467+0530 I  CONNPOOL [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Connecting to ac-mongo-node20:27017
 Unable to reach primary for set ac-dev
2024-07-01T09:36:15.541+0530 I  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Cannot reach any nodes for set ac-dev. Please check network connectivity and the status of the set

How do I correctly configure mongodb replica in docker properly and connect to it from host system?

You're exposing 27017 to different ports yet in rs.iniate the ports are 27017. Could it be the problem?
